# jQuery text rotator like https://sendgrid.com/

Tags: jquery, animation, text

I've used, and coded, some simple text rotators in the past but I'm trying to accomplish a similar effect that https://sendgrid.com/ uses on their home page.

Specifically, a Sentence with a set of words in the middle that fade/drop in and out, expanding the sentence as needed.. and with a loading line below it.

Also, as a no-js fallback I'd like to use HTML markup to control the rotated text, so it's not in a JS array or something..

Something like:

```
<h1>This is the 
    <span class="show">short</span>
    <span>longer</span>
    <span>Longest ever</span> 
    <span>craziest, super long</span>
sentence in the World!</h1>
```

Where, only the span with .show will be displayed in case of no-js.
And, where jQuery will rotate through these spans, toggling the class .show, expanding the area for the words to fade into...

I've found a gsap version, but haven't used that in the past and this project uses jQuery
But, here is the effect, for examples sake:
https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/BaNyyVP

Any ideas or suggestions!??

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what we came up with, and it works great!**
open the code snippet in the full window to see it properly (didn't include any media queries in the css of the example)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".scroller").each(function (i, scroller) {
    $(scroller).find(".strings-cont").addClass("no-width");

    const strings = $(scroller).find(".string");
    let active = 0;

    next = () => {
      strings.each((i, obj) => {
        i === active ? $(obj).addClass("active") : $(obj).removeClass("active");
      });
      const val = strings[active].offsetWidth + "px";
      $(scroller).find(".strings-cont").css("width", val);
      active = (active + 1) % strings.length;
    };
    setInterval(next, 3000);
    setTimeout(next, 0);
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #333;
}
.strings-cont {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: width 0.3s ease;
  justify-content: center;
}
.string {
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.string:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #3368fa;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.string.active {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  position: static;
  transform: translateX(0);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.string.active:before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2.7s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.no-width {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="scroller">
  This animation is&nbsp;
  <span class="strings-cont">
    <span class="string active">awesome</span>
    <span class="string">great</span>
    <span class="string">fantastic</span>
    <span class="string">boring</span>
  </span>
  &nbsp;don't you think?
</h1>
<h1 class="scroller">
  This is working&nbsp;
  <span class="strings-cont">
    <span class="string active">okay</span>
    <span class="string">better</span>
    <span class="string">nice</span>
    <span class="string">smoothly</span>
  </span>
  &nbsp;don't you think?
</h1>
<h1 class="scroller">
  -----------&nbsp;
  <span class="strings-cont">
    <span class="string active">you</span>
    <span class="string">get</span>
    <span class="string">the</span>
    <span class="string">point</span>
  </span>
  &nbsp;-----------
</h1>
```